# Unable to mount usb hard disk in rhel 7.1

Tags: redhat, usb-drive

**while am installing ntfs-3g rpm it shows**

> [root@localhost 64bit]# rpm -Uvh ntfs-3g-2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64.rpm 
>   warning: ntfs-3g-2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
>   Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
>           file /usr/bin/ntfs-3g conflicts between attempted installs of ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64 and ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64
>
> file /usr/bin/ntfsmount conflicts between attempted installs of
>   ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64 and ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64

**while am double clicking on my hard disk it shows**

Unable to access “Expansion Drive” Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /run/media/root/Expansion Drive: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs"-o"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=0,gid=0,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/run/media/root/Expansion Drive"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs'

Comment: This is not a [programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install epel repository from fedora

Download it from http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm

## # rpm -ivh epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm

## # yum install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs ntfsprogs-gnomevfs

Done